# Using Angularjs animation to change an element on hover

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, ng-animate

so this is just a sample of what I am trying to do. I want to use Angularjs to animate the opacity of the element on hover but I can't get it to do anything. I have been reading the documentation but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. Any help is appreciated. See example below.

http://jsbin.com/AdIXIKU/1/edit

Thank you in advance

Comment: In the context of ng-animate *enter* and *leave* refer to entering and leaving the animation showing or hiding and element, not a mouse interaction.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use `angular` if you want transitions on `hover`:

```css
.reveal-animation {
    // add the vendor prefixed versions as well
    transition: all 1s;
}

.reveal-animation:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Should be sufficient.

If you want to animate the *entering* and *leaving* of elements, you'll need to use some more angular constructs to ensure that elements do enter and leave like this: http://jsbin.com/iwudOjAW/1/edit (contains both `hover` and `enter`/`leave` effects).

I have used the [`ng-route` module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) and made the `ng-view` element `enter` and `leave` by changing the hash of the URL.

Comment: @aks. I am not sure which part of the question you are referring to. As far as I can see, there are two interpretations of OP's question: animating hover interactions using angular (from his text) or animating `ng-enter` and `ng-leave` (from his code). I have touched both bases in my answer: for the first: use CSS as angular doesn't have (and doesn't need) controls for that sort of behavior and, for the second: animating `ng-enter` and `ng-leave`. It is unclear which part wasn't addressed.